# Are "closed as duplicate" questions searchable?

Tags: support, duplicate-questions

I just had a question closed as a duplicate. I agree that it's a duplicate, but I think that search engine users would not find the original (as I didn't).

Is a question closed as a duplicate still indexed for search engines? If not, should I edit the original to make it more searchable?

Comment: How did you search - Google or the site search? If it's the latter I'm not surprised you didn't find it. Also having many search terms pointing to the answer is a good thing.

Comment: Well, yes. That's the whole point of leaving the duplicate hanging around. If they weren't indexed we'd just delete them. See also: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes, try it out for yourself: search Google for

> Why can I assign an undefined variable to itself in Ruby and get nil

and you'll find the top result (right now) is: [Template example in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7297478/template-example-in-c)

(I just picked a random, old, duplicate-closed question and took a unique-enough looking string from it.)

Try it with the first sentence in your question and it should work too.

Comment: I'm not sure you are right. Duplicate questions with no answers [are set as redirects](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271078/5447906) to the questions they duplicate. I don't think search engines put redirects to their index. Therefore I think such questions are not searchable. I can't find the above mentioned "Template example in C++" question in Google, even if [explicitly](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+%22Template+example+in+C%2B%2B%22) searching in Stack Overflow.